# How to skip writing dependencies in htmlwidgets::saveWidget()?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, r-plotly

When visualizing data with plotly, i want to write widgets as html-documents without `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` writing dependencies every time, assuming that these already are in place, to save processing time. The widgets need to be self-contained to save disk space.

```
library(plotly)
t <- Sys.time()
p <- plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "test.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = NULL)
print(Sys.time() - t)
```

`Time difference of 4.303076 secs` on my machine.

This produces ~6 mb of data only in depedencies (crosstalk-1.0.0, htmlwidgets-1.2, jquery-1.11.3, plotly-binding-4.7.1.9000, plotly-htmlwidgets-css-1.38.3, plotly-main-1.38.3, typedarray-0.1)

`htmlwidgets::saveWidget` writes dependencies although these files already exist. Can  this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

Good question.  I tried to answer inline in comments within the code.  `htmlwidgets` dependencies come from two sources: `htmlwidgets::getDependency()` and the `dependencies` element in the widget list.  Changing the `src` element within `dependencies` to `href` instead of `file` means these dependencies will not get copied.  However, the dependencies from `htmlwidgets::getDependency()` are harder to overwrite, but in the case will only copy `htmlwidgets.js` and `plotly-binding.js`, which are fairly small in comparison with the other four.

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")

# let's inspect our p htmlwidget list for clues
p$dependencies

# if the src argument for htmltools::htmlDependency
#   is file then the file will be copied
#   but if it is href then the file will not be copied

# start by making a copy of your htmlwidget
#   this is not necessary but we'll do to demonstrate the difference
p2 <- p

p2$dependencies <- lapply(
  p$dependencies,
  function(dep) {
    # I use "" below but guessing that is not really the location
    dep$src$href = "" # directory of your already saved dependency
    dep$src$file = NULL
    
    return(dep)
  }
)

# note this will still copy htmlwidgets and plotly-binding
#  requires a much bigger hack to htmlwidgets::getDependency() to change

t <- Sys.time()
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "test.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = NULL)
print(Sys.time() - t)

t <- Sys.time()
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p2), "test.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = NULL)
print(Sys.time() - t)
```